# Google Cloud Function can't call Cloud Function Service because of protocol error in jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl

Tags: java, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run, java-http-client

I have a Google Cloud Function that uses the `java.net.http.HttpClient` to send a GET request to the URL `https://userinfo-service-55555xyz-ew.a.run.app` (that is represting my Cloud Run Service).

Both the function and the run service are located in `europe-west1`.

However the following exception is thrown when calling the logic for the GET request.

```
java.io.IOException: Received RST_STREAM: Protocol error

at jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl.send ( jdk/internal.net.http/HttpClientImpl.java:565 )
at jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientFacade.send ( jdk/internal.net.http/HttpClientFacade.java:119 )
at com.myapp.functions.UserInit.callUserInfoService ( com/myapp.functions/UserInit.java:49 )
at com.myapp.functions.UserInit.service ( com/myapp.functions/UserInit.java:36 )
```

This is the Java code for the call:

```java
    private void callUserInfoService(String userId, String email) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String url = this.getUserInfoUrl() + "/init?auth0Id=" + userId + "&email=" + email;
        System.out.println("UserInfo URL used: " + url);

        var getRequest = java.net.http.HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(url)).GET().build();

        // Send the sendHttpRequest using the client
        var getResponse = client.send(getRequest, BodyHandlers.ofString());

        System.out.println("Received code " + getResponse.statusCode() + " from url " + url);
    }
```

Excerpt `gcloud run services describe userinfo-service --region=europe-west1`

```yaml
➜  cloud-functions git:(master) ✗ gcloud run services describe userinfo-service --region=europe-west1
✔ Service userinfo-service in region europe-west1
 
URL:     https://userinfo-service-55555xyz-ew.a.run.app
Ingress: all
Traffic:
  100% LATEST (currently userinfo-service-00001-qit)
 
Last updated on 2022-04-26T12:39:53.800502Z by falke2088@gmail.com:
  Revision userinfo-service-00001-qit
  Image:             eu.gcr.io/myapp/userinfo-service:95b5e56f-0162-4ac4-b5be-66f272884bb6
  Port:              8080
  Memory:            512Mi
  CPU:               1
  Service account:   981444444-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  Env vars:
    LOG_LEVEL        debug
    SQL_CONNECTION   10.113.160.3
    SQL_DATABASE     db
    SQL_PASSWORD     test
    SQL_USER         test
  Concurrency:       10
  Min Instances:     1
  Max Instances:     2
  Timeout:           3000s
  VPC connector:
    Name:            cloud-run-connector
    Egress:          private-ranges-only
```

Excerpt: `gcloud functions describe user-init --region=europe-west1`

```yaml
➜  cloud-functions git:(master) ✗ gcloud functions describe user-init --region=europe-west1
availableMemoryMb: 4096
buildId: 837b8cb5-8f01-49e6-96a6-15f344c36c1e
buildName: projects/98175493814/locations/europe-west1/builds/837b8cb5-8f01-49e6-96a6-15f344c36c1e
dockerRegistry: CONTAINER_REGISTRY
entryPoint: com.myapp.functions.UserInit
environmentVariables:
  HOOK_KEY: f0ec5d68-ceff-4293-8a34-ec08a0dcd124
  USERINFO_SERVICE_URL: https://userinfo-service-55555xyz-ew.a.run.app
httpsTrigger:
  securityLevel: SECURE_ALWAYS
  url: https://europe-west1-myapp.cloudfunctions.net/user-init
ingressSettings: ALLOW_ALL
labels:
  deployment-tool: cli-gcloud
name: projects/myapp/locations/europe-west1/functions/user-init
runtime: java11
serviceAccountEmail: myapp@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
sourceUploadUrl: https://storage.googleapis.com/uploads-123543534.europe-west1.cloudfunctions.appspot.com/679c703d-b788-45a0-a8fc-4347f08d7f7c.zip
status: ACTIVE
timeout: 60s
updateTime: '2022-04-26T13:12:19.064Z'
versionId: '7'
vpcConnector: projects/myapp/locations/europe-west1/connectors/cloud-run-connector
vpcConnectorEgressSettings: ALL_TRAFFIC
```

Comment: Which version of the JDK (and from which distribution) was this observed with? It might be related to https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8218546

Comment: good point but I can't downgrade to JDK 8. Only JDK 11 and 17 is available for Cloud Functions. I switcher over to OkHttp3 and now it works

Comment: The bug has been fix in 11.0.15 and shouldn't be present in 17, hence my question about which version of Java you were using? Also sometimes different vendor will backport a bug to different release versions - hence my question about the distribution too. java.net.http.HttpClient isn't present in JDK 8 anyway. So I don't understand the "downgrading" part.

Answer (score 1):

I use `OkHttp3` library now and it works